# Pandas changing dtype of date index after opening and saving csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, date-formatting

I use Pandas to read a `stock.csv` file consisting of historical, daily data.  Then the Date is set to the index and the daily data manipulated to weekly, finally saving the file.  The date in the daily csv file comes formatted `YYYMMDD`.

```
col_Names = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
df = pd.read_csv(path1 + 'CSL.csv', names=col_Names, parse_dates=['Date'])
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
print(df.index)

... # daily to weekly code...

df.to_csv(path2 + 'CSLW.csv')
```

As expected, `df.index` returns class `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp`

Opening the saved weekly file with Notepad shows the date format has been saved in the format `DD/MM/YYYY`, although I have not programmed any format.  Is it possible that Pandas or python is using the default for my location (Australia)?

Then when I open the weekly file using the same code as above, the dtype of `df.index` is returned as `Object`, even though the date has been parsed.  This is a nuisance because further manipulation requires datetime data, not strings.

I'd be most grateful for elucidation.

`CSL.csv  5 trading days`

```
19940606,0.80333333333333253,0.80666666666666586,0.7999999999999992,0.80333333333333253,1183200.00000000118,0
19940607,0.804333333333332529,0.80999999999999919,0.7999999999999992,0.80333333333333253,1570890.00000000157,0
19940608,0.80333333333333253,0.80666666666666586,0.7999999999999992,0.80666666666666586,921300.000000000921,0
19940609,0.80333333333333253,0.80666666666666586,0.80333333333333253,0.80666666666666586,1702200.0000000017,0
19940610,0.80333333333333253,0.80666666666666586,0.7999999999999992,0.80333333333333253,928350.000000000928,0
```

`CSLW.csv 2 weeks of trading days`

```
10/06/1994,0.80333333333333253,0.80666666666666586,0.7999999999999992,0.80333333333333253,928350.000000000928,0
14/06/1994,0.803999999999999196,0.80666666666666586,0.80333333333333253,0.80666666666666586,1372302.00000000137,0
```

Comment: Can you place a couple of lines of the csv file?

Comment: You have 6 column names for 7 columns worth of data. Or is that last column in your `CSL.csv` not supposed to be there?

Comment: Apologies.  The last column in the (daily) CSL.csv is dropped before making the (weekly) CSLW.csv file.  It's something called "open interest" and is always zero in Australian Security Exchange equity data files.